# Driver [] is not supported

Tags: laravel-5

Verán, estoy haciendo una url con la que ver imágenes de una tabla de plantas.
web.php:

```
Route::get('/images/{path}/{attachment}', function($path, $attachment){
    $storagePath = Storage::disk($path)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $imageFilePath = $storagePath . $attachment;

    if(File::exists($imageFilePath)){
        return Image::make($imageFilePath)->response();
    }
});
```

La función en plantas.php:

```
public function rutas(){
        return "images/fotos/" . $this->foto;
    }
```

Y el código en filesystems.php:

```
'planta' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/fotos'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Tras esto, tengo en `\storage\app\fotos` una imagen llamada `cactus.jpg`, por lo que tras activar `php artisan serve`, escribo `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/fotos/cactus.jpg`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estará fallando?

Edito: He probado a hacer antes de `$storagePath` el código `dd("Hola")`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí funciona, pero si está antes de `$imageFilePath`, vuelve a saltarme el mensaje de error. Es decir el error esta en el codigo `$storagePath = Storage::disk($path)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();`

Más cosas: Voy a incluir el contenido del fichero .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:W3VBG3wxQtSobMUgXfRC5B1+A5hKAQqqp67ll1DiQe0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=plantas
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el "disco" por defecto que utilizas? me refiero a esta línea, y a tu configuración de .env: `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),`

Comment: @Shaz No entiendo tu pregunta, pero he añadido el fichero .env por si te sirve. Si con disco te refieres al disks de filesystems.php, es 'planta' el cual esta mencionado aqui.